# path enumeration using prime numbers(insert child)

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a little help,

I have a table tree which has following data:

```
 id | person | prime | product
----+--------+-------+---------
  1      x       2       2
  2      z       3       6
  4      d       5       30
```

How this works is

Prime and products are used to calculate the parent child relationship of my family.
Prime = next available prime number
Product = (prime * product of parent). Each product of primes can only be divided by those primes.

for person d parent is z  since 5(prime of d) * 6 (productof z) = 30(product of d)

Using the same principle I have to write a singe query to insert child of d (say a,b,c) to the table.

Provided there is another table prime_numbers with column primes which holds the list of prime numbers (2,3,5,7,11,13,17,....)

I had consulted [**This**](http://books.google.com.np/books?id=8NdQY8TuEDUC&pg=PA180&lpg=PA180&dq=prime%20tree%20structure%20sql&source=bl&ots=D94D8K77nZ&sig=y2HcefUDJ2K19aF8y3_6LJmgSxo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LsRgT-mRKcOxrAeC4ODzBQ&sqi=2&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false).

But was unable to derive the solution from it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have mySql installed so I can't check this, but maybe it can be a start.
You can use an `Insert-select` based on a join of some subqueries:

1. a subquery for getting a list of next prime numbers
2. from your_table, get the father (id=4)
3. join of 1 + 2 for calculating next pruducts and adding row number
4. a subquery for the new persons (I unioned constants) with row number
5. join of 3 + 4 according to row number

So it may look like:

```
SELECT prsns.idd, prsns.namee, t1.nxt, t1.product
FROM
(SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 'rn', p.nxt prime, p.nxt * tt.product product
(SELECT cur, max(nxt) as nxt
FROM 
( select t.prime as cur, nxtt.prime as nxt
  from prime_numbers t, prime_numbers nxtt
  where t.prime > nxtt.prime )
GROUP BY cur
ORDER BY nxt) p, your_table tt, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
WHERE tt.id = 4
AND p.nxt > tt.prime) t1,
(
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 'rn', idd, namee
FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, (
  select 5 as idd, 'a' as namee union
  select 6 , 'b' union
  select 7 , 'c' union
)
) prsns
WHERE prsns.rn = t1.rn
```

Comment: could you please tell me what is prsns ? I am a beginner with sql but just wondering would this insert the childs ?

Comment: Prsns is the alias I gave the subquery with the union of a,b and c constants. If this query gives you the results that you want then add the insert scope.

Comment: sorry but didn't get the result

Comment: As I said, I can't test it. Try to run every subquery by its own. I'm also not sure as for the way I get the rownum - try to remove it (but then you'll have to find some other way)